# Dropzone remove all file except first file

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Just simple ask, I have code like this on JavaScript on dropzone

```
addRemoveLinks: true,
maxFiles: 1,
init: function() {
  this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
        swal("Error", "U just can upload 1 file", "warning");
  });
}
```

Well is kind a work the file not upload if I have a file, but that file (not first one) still show even they not uploaded, I need to remove all file (not first one) automatic if they didn't upload or get alert. How can I did that???

Comment: i dont need to be rude, but pls answer my question not my spell -__-

Answer (score 0):

You can call the removeFile() method, also if you want the thumbnail to show for a moment with the message you can add a timeout:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    maxFiles: 1,
    dictMaxFilesExceeded: "U just can upload 1 file",
    init: function () {
        var myDropzone = this;
        this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                myDropzone.removeFile(file);
            }, 3000);
        });
    },

};
```